# ArcGIS display multiple popup at the same time?

Tags: popup, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, infowindow

I'm using ArcGIS API v4 and the document said ArcGIS API allows view can only have one instance of popup at a time

> All Views contain a default popup. This popup can display generic content, which is set in its title and content properties. When content is set directly on the Popup instance it is not tied to a specific feature or layer.

I've been searching for similar questions but still got no clearly answers? Is there a way to implement opening multiple popup on ArcGIS map at the same time?

Comment: The popup is a singleton type of object, meaning only one popup in a map.

Comment: Thanks @kenbuja, yeah since popup is singleton, I'm looking for an idea of how to extend or customize it show it can display more than one at a time

Comment: Are you looking to display multiple of these all the time (like a fancy label) or is it that when people click on them you want them to remain?  Either way, there's probably a better solution than trying to use the Popup for this.

Comment: @BjornSvensson yes I want it to stay remain when people click away out of popup or open another popups. Do you have any recommends? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Hung, while the "Popup" widget is a singleton, the "[Feature](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Feature.html)" widget can be used to display information normally found in the Popup without having to use the Popup itself. The documentation includes samples for showing the Feature widget in a side panel, and you could for example expand that to have multiple side panels, or display it somewhere else.